# размер блока с содержимым и без

Tags: javascript, html, css

имеется динамически изменяемый блок, содержимое которого может быть на страницу и больше( если содержимое меньше или равно, надо растянуть блок на всю длину страницы ) если больше: брать длину содержимого 
(желательно на сss)

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 90; i++) {
  setTimeout(function timer() {
    $('.a').append('Доброе утро ' + i + '<br>' );
  }, i * 100);
}
```

```css
.a{
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  position: absolute;
  padding:50px 10px 60px 10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измени `absolute на relative`

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 90; i++) {
  setTimeout(function timer() {
    $('.a').append('Доброе утро ' + i + '<br>');
  }, i * 100);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

body {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.a {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px 10px 60px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Второй вариант. Оставь как есть изначально, убери `bottom:0;`

Но это будет не верным решением. Обрати внимание, что `body` у тебя не растянется

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 90; i++) {
  setTimeout(function timer() {
    $('.a').append('Доброе утро ' + i + '<br>');
  }, i * 100);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

body {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.a {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 50px 10px 60px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Ну а если надо что бы красный блок без содержания имел минимум высоту экрана,
Если я правильно понял ну тогда `min-height: 100vh;` и придется отказаться от 
`position: relative;`

Ну а если `position: relative;` или `position: absolute;` обязательно, то тогда это можно реализовать js-скриптом

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 90; i++) {
  setTimeout(function timer() {
    $('.a').append('Доброе утро ' + i + '<br>');
  }, i * 100);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

body {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.a {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 50px 10px 60px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: Красный в вашем варианте растягивается, а должен при пустом(или маленьком)  контенте быть на всю страницу, в случае  превышения размера- начинать растягиваться

Comment: Посмотри третий вариант